# React-Select search input -Turkish lowercase "i" character does not work to get results (words) starting with "İ"

Tags: reactjs, react-select

In my app, I'm using `react-select` component for selecting city functionality. Component renders Turkish Cities. So, some city names start with Turkish character "İ-i". everything works good.But the thing is that, when I type lowercase "i", I can't get city names starting with "İ", like İzmir, İstanbul.

Here is my component

```
import Select from 'react-select';
import {
  FormGroup,
  Input,
  Label,
  Col,
} from 'reactstrap';

<FormGroup row>
  <Col xs="12" md="9">
    <Label htmlFor="text-input">{t('RESTAURANT_DETAILS.GENERAL_INFO.CITY')}</Label>
    <Select
      placeholder={i18n.t('CHOOSE_CITY')}
      isDisabled={!this.state.editable || accountingLoading}
      options={this.state.cities.map(city => ({
        value: city.code,
        label: city.city,
      }))}
      value={this.state.city}
      onChange={val => this.onCitySelected(val)}
    />
  </Col>
</FormGroup>
```

So, to get those cities I should type exactly uppercase "İ". Is there any way to fix this issue? I'm stuck with this annoying bug.

Here are screenshots of cases.

[https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/1/fa7b5ca6e264501abb395b4ac38c753d-full.png](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/1/4c6f5c8e1c891a3d2ae8ee38dbfadb79-full.png)

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/1/4c6f5c8e1c891a3d2ae8ee38dbfadb79-full.png

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/1/0c3ae965754e60a015ea048ddd081f51-full.png

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/1/7ee3c8187ea4830386ff45cbd40ee126-full.png

**--- UPDATE ---**
I solved it out guys.

I added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the latin character i to also represent the turkish character İ, you will need to either replace the turkish characters in your `label` with latin characters (a poor solution since I'm sure you want to show them that way) or provide a custom filter function to react select that will support that character duality.

```
filterOption={this.customFilter}
```

Here is an example to replace turkish characters in a string

`.replace(/İ/gim, "i")`

And here is an example custom filter.

```
customFilter = (option, searchText) => {
   if (
     option.data.label.includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
   ) {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, man. Actually, it worked. But now, another issue came up. react-select search works elastic. I mean, for example it brings the city named "Giresun" even though you typed "Ğiresun".("Ğ" is another Turkish character)
So, by the moment I added custom filter to component, I lost that elasticity. Now, I should type everything accurately.

Comment: Not sure about that, but what it does do is search all the data fields on <option> at once, so in your case: label and value. If you want to keep the original search function, what you can do is add another data field where you replace all the Turkish characters with latin characters and it should search that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution. here is it, with regex.
Now works perfect.

```
export const turkishCharacterRegex = keyword => keyword
  .replace(/[ıİiI]/g, '[ıİiI]')
  .replace(/[şŞsS]/g, '[şŞsS]')
  .replace(/[çÇcC]/g, '[çÇcC]')
  .replace(/[ğĞgG]/g, '[ğĞgG]')
  .replace(/[öÖoO]/g, '[öÖoO]')
  .replace(/[üÜuU]/g, '[üÜuU]');


 const customFilter = (option, searchText) =>((turkishCharacterRegex(option.data.label)).toLowerCase().includes(turkishCharacterRegex(searchText).toLowerCase()));

    <Select
      -----
      -----
      -----
      filterOption={customFilter}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and my solution was to use `toLocaleLowerCase` method. It's probably easier to understand than regexes.

```js
<Select
  ...

  filterOption={(option, query) =>
    String(option.data.label)
      .toLocaleLowerCase('tr')
      .includes(query.toLocaleLowerCase('tr'))
  }

  ...
/>
```